# Proper way of passing textbox data with post in AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, post

Right now I am using this, and it works perfectly, but for some reason I don't think this is the best or most efficient way to accomplish this task. It seems like it will get messy as I start to add more textbook inputs. Please review:

index.html:

```
function saveUserData(userData) {
  $.post('userData.php', {
    textbox1: document.getElementById('textbox1').value,
    textbox2: document.getElementById('textbox2').value, 
    userData: JSON.stringify(userData)
  }, function(data) {
    return true; 
  });
```

html:

```
<input name="textbox1" type="textbox1" id="textbox1">
<input name="textbox2" type="textbox2" id="textbox2">
```

userdata.php:

```php
$userData = json_decode($_POST['userData']);
$textbox1 = $_POST['textbox1'];
$textbox2 = $_POST['textbox2'];
//Insert user data
$query = "INSERT INTO users SET first_name = '".$userData->first_name."', last_name = '".$userData->last_name."', email = '".$userData->email."', picture = '".$userData->picture->data->url."', created = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."', modified = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."',test1 = '".$textbox1."',test2 = '".$textbox2."' ";
$insert = $db->query($query);
```

Comment: take a look at http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ , it allows you to serialize an entire form, so you don't need to add every form input one by one

Comment: @Bdloul was about to suggest the same thing. OP would also need to work in that `userData` via something like `serializedForm + '&userData=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(userData))`

Comment: Your DB structure will not scale well to more "textbox" inputs. Consider a [one-to-many relational model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)). Also, you should be using prepared statements and parameter binding to protect your database from SQL injection attacks

Comment: Thanks, I am kinda picking up what you guys are throwing down. Could you give me examples using the code I provided with serialization, well well as how to properly use prepared statements and parameter binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Ok, how about something like this?

```
//javascript
var toPost = {};
$("input").each(function() {
    toPost[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val()
});

var inputs = JSON.stringify(toPost);
//send postJSON to php with $.post()

//in php
$inputs = json_decode($_POST["inputs"], true);
//now all the inputs can be accessed
foreach ($inputs as $name => $val) {
     echo "input with name '$name' has value $val";
     //you can do all you prepared statements and stuff with these values.
}
```

Much more general and will automatically convert your inputs to a json object with the name of the input used as the key. Don't use $(":input") as this will include things like buttons.

--- OLD ANSWER: ---

Can't really test this right now, but could you do something like:

```
//javascript:
var i = 1;
while ($('#textbox'+i).length != 0) {
    postObject['textbox'+i] = $('#textbox'+i).val();
    i++;
}
//postObject values are then added to the $.post call

//php:
$i = 1;
$query = "INSERT INTO users SET first_name = '".$userData->first_name."', last_name = '".$userData->last_name."', email = '".$userData->email."', picture = '".$userData->picture->data->url."', created = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."', modified = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."'";
while (isset($_POST["textbox$i"])) {
    $query .= ", test$i = '".$_POST["textbox$i"]."'";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: I didn't intend on calling them all "textbook1","2" though... I just put that in for an example.

Comment: Edited with a more general answer to just grab all input values and send them to the server